# How would I constrain my CONCAT statement to just the id from the if statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, concatenation

I've been beating my head against the wall for a while now on this.  I've tried following the thought behind [Concat in If statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993012/concat-in-if-statement) but I can't seem to figure out a way to make my specific need work. I'm now down to a syntax error in my CONCAT statement..'WHERE req.reqCreatedBy = '0' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE users.firstname,' ',users.lastn'. Could anybody give me some help on bringing the first and last name in on this query?  I'm at a complete loss.

```
SELECT req.reqID as Id,
reqDesc.titleText as Title,
req.reqCity as City,
req.reqState as State,
req.areaID as Area,
area.areaname,
reqType.typeTitle as Type,
req.reqCreatedDate as Created,
req.reqEndDate as `End`, 
CONCAT((CASE WHERE req.reqCreatedBy = '0' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE users.firstname,' ',users.lastname END))
AS Recruiter
FROM apps_job_request as req
INNER JOIN apps_job_request_description as reqDesc
ON req.reqTitle = reqDesc.titleID
INNER JOIN apps_job_request_type as reqType
ON reqDesc.typeID = reqType.typeID
INNER JOIN `assemble_users`.area AS area
ON area.areaid = req.areaID
INNER JOIN `assemble_users`.users AS users
ON users.username = req.reqCreatedBy 
WHERE req.reqID is not null
AND req.reqActive = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If check only one value `req.reqCreatedBy`, there may be simple IF statement, use CASE for multiple checked values.

```
SELECT req.reqID          as Id,
       reqDesc.titleText  as Title,
       req.reqCity        as City,
       req.reqState       as State,
       req.areaID         as Area,
       area.areaname,
       reqType.typeTitle  as Type,
       req.reqCreatedDate as Created,
       req.reqEndDate     as `End`,
       -- req.reqCreatedBy is '0' OR ''?
       IF(req.reqCreatedBy = '0', 'Unknown', CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname)) AS Recruiter
FROM apps_job_request as req
         INNER JOIN apps_job_request_description as reqDesc
                    ON req.reqTitle = reqDesc.titleID
         INNER JOIN apps_job_request_type as reqType
                    ON reqDesc.typeID = reqType.typeID
         INNER JOIN `assemble_users`.area AS area
                    ON area.areaid = req.areaID
         INNER JOIN `assemble_users`.users AS users
                    ON users.username = req.reqCreatedBy
WHERE req.reqID is not null
  AND req.reqActive = '1'
```

Comment: That was one of my first attempts.  It pulls, but instead of about 700 rows, it gives me nearly 10 million.

Comment: So, I mistake with `req.reqCreatedBy` - it seems to be varchar type, if not set then value is '0' or empty ''?. This value is unique in database?

Comment: It is a varchar. reqCreatedBy is the username from the users schema example would be req.reqCreatedBy = '252552' = users.username.  And to answer your question, req.reqCreatedBy would be either '0' (varchar 0) or '252552' (varchar username)

Comment: There's `users.username` and `reqCreatedBy` as joined keys only?  You have any records with empty `reqCreatedBy`?

Comment: I just checked,  they are all '0' or 'A_Number' Maybe I'm going about it wrong.  What about if I change all the '0's to 'unknown' in the table or maybe a username of a test account or something? It could get rid of the IF statement and simplify the query a bit.

Comment: There's no problem with IF/CONCAT. There may be trouble with JOIN `ON users.username = req.reqCreatedBy`. If you use INNER JOIN and users.username are unique 'A_number' and non-empty then query return expected num of rows. If you JOIN lot of same or empty values then you got unexcpected num of rows.

Comment: That got it.  I set the req.reqCreatedBy as an INT and not a VARCHAR.  Once I corrected that mistake and got the collation set correctly,  it now gives the expected results  Thank you for your help. If you put an answer up about the JOINS being the problem I will gladly mark it as the answer since it put me on to looking at my structure.

Comment: Super. If I want check JOINs then I must know more details about  structure of databases and relationships between tables.